# Apache Spark: Issues with saveAsTextFile() and filter()

Tags: java, apache-spark

When I try to use the function `saveAsTextFile()` I always get empty files even that the RDD contains tuples:

```
myRDD.saveAsTextFile("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/chna.txt");
```

What can be the reason?

Let's assume that it works and the data is registered in the textfile, how can I retrieve it through the shell or through my code (note: I am using Java)?

Does any solution exist to modify a text file through my code (using Java always), I tried the following code but got an `java.io.NotSerializableException` , is there any other possible solution?

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/chn.txt", true)); 
pairsRDD.foreach(x -> bufferedWriter.write(x._1+" "+x._2)); 
bufferedWriter.newLine();  // ... 
bufferedWriter.close();
```

When I used this line of code:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> filterRDD = pairsRDD.filter((x,y) -> (x._1.equals(y._1))&&(x._2.equals(y._2)))));
```

I got an `IOException` , is it caused because the RDD is empty? Or the condition used for filter is wrong?

How can I fix this problem and what is the reason of it?

> java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe
>   in the Hadoop binaries.

When I create the RDD, it takes the first line (name of fields) too, how can I avoid this? Because I want to take only the lines which contains values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`saveAsTextFile()` takes a path to a folder as parameter, not a path to a file. It will actually write one file per partition in that folder, named part-r-xxxxx (xxxxx being 00000 to whatever number of partitions you have).

To read your data again, it's a simple as using `sparkContext.textFile()` or `.wholeTextFile()` methods (depending whether you want to read a single file or a full folder).

There's no simple solution in spark to modify a file in place, since you don't control the naming of whatever spark writes, and spark forbids writing in a non empty folder in the first place.

If you really want to do that, the best thing to do is to not use spark, since it's not a matter of distributed computing, and use e.g sed or awk to do in place file editing, which will be orders of magnitude more performant, and a one liner.

Comment: thanx , what about other questions?

Comment: thanx , what about other questions? 1. how can i eliminate the first line of my file  which contains name of fields such (id name job sex.... ) bcz i want only the lines which contain values  2. i get an IOException in this line of code :    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf); the detail o this exception is : Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries. and when i tried to download winutils.exe and installed t i got this message :the program cant start bcz MSVCR100.dll is misssing , so how can i solve it please

Comment: 1. Use a .filter() on your RDD to keep only lines you want
2. I don't know, I never tried to used spark on windows. I honestly would rather install an ubuntu VM than fix this ^^

Comment: for 1. i dont want to use filter () bcz it ll sweep the whole RDD and i want to eliminate only the first line

Comment: There's no operation nor transformation on a RDD that doesn't sweep the whole RDD I'm afraid. But honestly, you won't even notice the cost, since it will be inlined with reading the data in the first place.

Comment: even if i use it for large data, it won't be noticeble,?

Comment: It shouldn't : it's applied immediately after reading the file, and disk access (even hitting RAM) is already order of magnitudes slower than the filtering you're doing.

Comment: i used the function saveAsTextFile ()  and it generate an empty file  again even that i gave it a path of a folder this time!!!!! could it has ny relatin with the IOException?

Comment: when i fixed the problem of the exception , the issue with saving is solved too :)